# Eclipse guide for beginners

Tags: eclipse

Can you please assist me to compile **A beginner's guide for Eclipse IDE**, similar to [Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide) & [Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170338/mercurial-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide) Guide in Stackoverflow.

A Beginner is someone unfamiliar in advanced java or software development.

Resources:
[Eclipse Newcomers FAQ](http://www.eclipse.org/home/newcomers.php) 
[Eclipse Java IDE - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html)
[Eclipse And Java: Free Video Tutorials](http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/index.html)

[Eclipse Resources](http://www.eclipse.org/resources/)(beginners and advanced - 379 articles)

Comment: is this a question or a statement(since you provided links)?

Comment: Its a community wiki for all resources or tips for a beginner using eclipse

Comment: Just ad on "Can you please assist me?", in your head, there's your question.

Answer (score 5):

**Eclipse and Java for Total Beginners**

http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/totalbeginner.html

Comment: +1, What does 'Hungarian captions' mean, Hungarian notations?
Is there a similar guide for newer versions of eclipse 3.4/3.5

Answer (score 1):

http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/eclipse/eclipse_tutorial_3.3.html

Comment: Thats very basic, i need detailed resources for absolute beginners

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse wiki is a good resource. http://wiki.eclipse.org/Main_Page