# How can I use Eclipse in a more efficient way

Tags: eclipse, ide

I've been using Eclipse for C++ and Java for a couple of years.
I have a feeling that I'm not taking full advantage of its capabilities. I see things on the menu like "Refactor" and "Navigate" which I don't have any idea what they are or how could they be used and I really want to use it more efficiently. I need a linear easy-to-understand guide on how to use it in plain english. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Please, be more precise, what you want to know. The sheer number of built-in refactoring and navigation options makes it improbable that someone will provide a full list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcoming you to the world of eclipse.

Please take a look at the following similar question which has had some interesting answers.

[Eclipse guide for beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385134/eclipse-guide-for-beginners)

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to check out the [official help system](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp), if you haven't done that already. You'll find the information you're looking for there.

The "Workbench User Guide" in there might interest you the most, as well as "Java development user guide" and "C/C++ Development User Guide". You can also use the systems built-in search capabilities to search for any particular topic that interests you.