# Java Programming using eclipse

Tags: java

how do you compile in Eclipse? And how do you run the program using this given with the choices: Java Applet or Java Application?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385134/eclipse-guide-for-beginners) contains some good resources for Eclipse newcomer, you might need it :)

Comment: See http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#firstjava_run

Answer (score 1):

If **Project -> Build Automatically** is enabled, you will compile when saving your work.

To run it, you have an arrow in a green circle in your toolbar (6th tool if you have a default benchmark). It will run the project using the currently showing class as a main class if it has a *main* method, or the last run main if it doesn't. Alternatively, you can use the keyboard shortcut **CTRL+F11**.

If you click on the little down arrow next to the green button, you can access to a history of classes you ran and to the **Run configuration**, which allows you for example to run a program with parameters or, what interrests you here, to choose to run it as an applet or an application.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the option: **Project > Build Automatically**

If you have a `main` method, run as Java Application. To create a main, type `main` then ctrl+space and select "main method" to have eclipse auto create it for you.