# How do I run an AndroidDriver test with Junit?

Tags: android, android-emulator, junit, eclipse-plugin, android-2.2-froyo

I've been following the instructions at:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver

And I've managed to get the following working so far:

- Installed Android SDK
- Updated it
- Made and ran an AVD image
- Installed Eclipse and ADT plugin but haven't learnt Eclipse yet. (I'm trying to compile things from the command line only.)
- Ran the emulation on the Android emulator
- Install WebDriver APK on Emulation using adb -s  -e install -r
- Set up portforwarding for the above
- Webdriver started is displayed on the emulator
- Downloaded selenium-java-x.jar
- Downloaded junit-x.jar
- Determined classpath for compiling the code
- Compiled using javac, I don't know if this is right:

  javac -classpath c:_projects\junit\junit-4.10.jar;c:_projects\selenium-java\selenium-java-2.17.0.jar OneTest.java

Here is my test:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; //VERY IMPORTANT. This line is not in the example on the Selenium AndroidDriver website.
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver;

public class OneTest extends TestCase 
{
  public void testGoogle() throws Exception 
  {
    WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver();

    // And now use this to visit Google
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    // Find the text input element by its name
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

    // Enter something to search for
    element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

    // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
    element.submit();

    // Check the title of the page
    System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

Now I'm stuck on this section:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver#Build_the_Android_Code

Where do I run these commands? For example $./go android_client etc. I think I just need to know how to compile properly and how to forward this test to the emulator. But I could be totally on the wrong track.

My versions are:

- Eclipse: 3.7.1
- Selenium server: 2.17.0
- AndroidDriver: 2.16.0
- Android SDK Tools Revision 16

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't more interest in this one.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind the steps you have taken so far and this excerpt :

> Now I'm stuck on this section:
>   http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver#Build_the_Android_Code
>
> Where do I run these commands? For example $./go android_client etc

The section is for building the Andriod WebDriver code. I suggest that you do not try running these commands as that section is not required to run the tests, which is your intention as  gathered from the excerpt below :

> I think I just need to know how to compile properly and how to
>   forward this test to the emulator. But I could be totally on the wrong
>   track.

Basically  you have done all the foundation work and at this point all you need to do is run the test file.

You could try:

There is some useful information about  getting up and running on Eclipse [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1385134/948641). Assuming that you have Eclipse running (Junit is already plugged in with eclipse) , you could right click your test  file in the Package Explorer window on Eclipse, then click Run As > Junit Test.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok. I tried to right click > run as Junit > I got: Errors exist in required project. android_test. Proceed with launch? The way I've created my project is by adding all the jars I think are needed in sources. So I thought I needed selenium_java_x.jar plus junit-x.jar so I added those in. But running generates thousands of errors for things which are not found. Like: "AfterMethod cannot be resolved to a type...". The test has no other required sources apart from those. So am I creating a junit project or android project, and do I need all of these sources?

Comment: You should be creating an Android Project.You could add the selenium_java jar. I don't think you would need the junit-x.jar. You should see the options you see when you right click the file and click Run As .

Comment: Also you have mentioned about "AfterMethod".which I don't see used in the test script you have pasted.Do you have other files in the workspace.

Comment: There are thousands of those which are caused by importing the jars into the project. AfterMethod was just the first one. I decided to award you with the bounty, congratulations.