# Correct command to retrieve remote mercurial updates pushed from my second machine

Tags: mercurial, repository, local

I'm new to Mercurial.

1. I `initialized` a Mercurial project on **`Machine A`**, `committed` my changes and `uploaded` them to a remote repository.
2. Then I `cloned` that repository on **`Machine B`**, `committed` some additional changes and `uploaded` them to the same remote repository.

In both cases, I uploaded the changes with the same command:

```
hg push https://username:password@domain/user/repository/
```

**Now I'm back on Machine A and I'm not sure how to update my local repository with the last changes I uploaded to the remote repository from Machine B.**

The commands `hg clone` or `hg pull` look like they might work but I'm not sure.

Would appreciate any guidance. Thanks.

Comment: See "Sharing Changes" in the Mercurial book: http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-the-basics.html#id347917

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`hg pull` will transfer any remote changesets not present in your local repo. Afterwards, you'll need to either `hg update` or `hg merge` depending on the presence of local changes.

Answer (score 4):

Use `hg pull`; pull transfers only changesets which are missing in the *existing* destination repository.
`hg clone` creates local copy of a remote repository.

See also this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397658/is-pull-a-synonym-for-clone-in-a-mercurial-source-control-repository).