# Mercurial log interface

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I've been going through the tutorial at hginit.com, but I've found a rather inconvenient aspect of the `hg log` feature. Basically, when I type it, I get the newest changes on top, and the oldest at the bottom. But this is simply annoying, as most of the time, you want to see the newest revisions. So... say I have 100 changesets, and I want to have a look over the 98th one. Do I scroll all the way up? Or is there a way to make Hg (Mercurial) list the changes the other way around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `hg log -r:`

Comment: Both this and David Sykes' responses work, so I've upvoted both. I'm choosing this because I have to choose an 'accepted answer' and this is the shorter way :)

Comment: It's clearly the better way, I also upvoted, but left mine in as it might be helpful

Answer (score 4):

Just limit the display of `hg log` with `-l/--limit`.

E.g. `hg log -l 100` to only display 100 changes.

If you want to avoid scrolling, you can also pipe the output to a pager (e.g. `hg log | less`) or use the [pager extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PagerExtension).

Comment: No, this is not what I had in mind. So basically, when I write `hg log`, I get something like

*latest change*\
*second latest change*\
*thirst latest change*\
*...*\
*first change*\

But I want it to be
*first change*\
*second change*\
*...*\
*latest change*\

I don't need to limit the number of changesets displayed.

Comment: Umm, if you limit the number of changes to 5, then you'll see latest change, second latest change, ..., fourth latest change, fifth latest change.

Comment: @XLR3204S, I think your problem is because the latest changes are on top. So you want to avoid scrolling? Just use a pager, or display less revisions (with `--limit`).

Answer (score 2):

```
hg log | tail -r
```

Answer (score 0):

For me second part of @tonfa's answer is the right one, useful in all cases (you can search with /, etc...)

> If you want to avoid scrolling, you can also pipe the output to a pager (e.g. hg log | less) or use the [pager extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PagerExtension).

By now, seems if you want the pager to work with your alias you must say specifically on your .hgrc (the same for hg help, esencial)

Example

```
[extensions]
pager =  

[pager]
pager = LESS='FRX' less
attend = help logg

[alias]
logg = log -G --template '\x1B[33m{node|short}\x1B[0m | {date|isodatesec} | \x1B[32m{author|user}\x1B[0m: {desc|strip|firstline}\n'
```