# Are there any accepted "best" or canonical books on SCM for developers?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I'm looking for any books considered best practice, canon, etc. on source code management (SCM) practices for developers.   Something that gives guidance on how and when to branch, how and when to merge, version number schemes, etc.

Perhaps with an eye towards distributed SCM tools like git (vs svn/cvs?), geographically distributed vs. centrally located development teams, differences between practices during forward development and post production, etc.

Comment: Any chance you can give more specific details about the process and tools you are interested in? Effective strategies for using SCM depend on both your development process and your SCM tools; "when should I branch?" probably has a very different answer if you are using SVN than if you are using git and "post production" means different things depending on if you are releasing binary packages or pushing continuous releases to a web service.

Comment: Resource recommendation requests are off topic here.

Comment: > Resource recommendation requests are off topic here. – EJoshuaS    
              ...he says, 5 1/2 years later.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure there is *one* book, but at least you have:

- [Source Control HOWTO](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html) from Erik Sink (founder of Source Gear) is a good introduction.
- For branches, the [chapter 7 How Software Evolves](http://oreilly.com/catalog/practicalperforce/chapter/ch07.pdf) of [Practical Perforce](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101855/) from Laura Wingerd is very instructive.

Answer (score 2):

Not paper books however you should check :

- [Mercurial: The Definitive Guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/) and [Mercurial for Beginners: The Definitive Practical Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170338/mercurial-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide).
- [Pro Git Book](http://progit.org/book/), [Git Community Book](http://book.git-scm.com/) and [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide).
- [Version Control with Subversion (Book)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).
- And the [InfoQ: Distributed Version Control Systems: A Not-So-Quick Guide Through](http://www.infoq.com/articles/dvcs-guide).