# Simple way to manage solo project across multiple computers

Tags: svn, networking, project-management, codeblocks

I am wanting to work on a project from multiple computers on the same network. If it matters, I am using Code::Blocks across multiple OSes.

What would be a good way to do this? Set up an SVN server on one of the computers?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on *how* you plan to work on multiple computers?

Comment: May be SVN is not good idea? Try to use any distributed version control system such as mercurial or git

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, stay away from [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/).

The best solution is using a [DVCS (Distributed Version Control System)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Version_Control_System). There are many of them available, while the most famous are [Git](http://git-scm.com/) and [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/). After you understand the basic concepts, they are far easier, faster and more powerful than SVN. They are also trivial to setup (while SVN requires a central server, which requires more work and some infrastructure).

Personally, I prefer Hg over Git. On the other hand, I realize that [GitHub](http://github.com/) website and its community is larger and better than [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org/).

I highly recommend reading [**Hg Init: a Mercurial tutorial**](http://hginit.com/), written by [Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/). If you feel like reading, I've also written [Things you should know about Mercurial](http://my.opera.com/CrazyTerabyte/blog/2010/07/03/things-you-should-know-about-mercurial) in my blog.

Related questions:

- [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide-closed)
- [Mercurial for Beginners: The Definitive Practical Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170338/mercurial-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Comment: Note, however, that you don't need BitBucket in order to share your commits in your local network. Heck, you don't even need a central server (although that is damn handy)! You can simply run `hg serve` each time you want to "serve" your commits to another machine. Well, you don't even need network connectivity (see `hg bundle`). However, I agree that a central server makes things a lot simpler and streamlined.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest route would be to use Git across the multiple machines, since that way it won't be OS-dependent and you won't need a centralized repos (as you would if you went with SVN). Because setting up Git is beyond the scope of this answer, I would point you to this answer to cover the setup that'd work for you: [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on your preferred flavour of source control system but since you've mentioned SVN, I'd just go and grab [Visual SVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). It's super easy to get up and running (allow 5 minutes), free and will work just fine across your network. I run it in both a large enterprise environment on a server with hundreds of repositories and users and on my local machine and it works equally well in both scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I use SVN, and I'm happy with it, though it does require a central server, I just use my 'always on' web server.

That said, I believe the trend is towards GIT, so I'd probably use that if I was starting afresh.